# Toolbox issue for RDLC in design mode VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, rdlc, toolbox

I am attempting to design an RDLC report, however my toolbox is filled with about 10 "Textbox" controls and an odd, empty #13119 control group.  I can find no other controls.  I have attempted several command line switches to rebuild the VS cache, but nothing works.  Do I need to point to a particular DLL to pull in the toolbox controls?  Tell me I don't need to reinstall VS2008.

Comment: Also, let me say that a "Reset Toolbox" does nothing except change the number of "Textbox" controls.

Comment: Nevermind...found the fix: http://zinovate.com/weblog/archive/2009/01/16/38234.aspx

Comment: i am facing the same issue and your solution is not working for me ....

Answer (score 2):

My good sense tells me that something got corrupted either in your installation.

Here's what I would try before attempting a repair (this happened recently):

I fixed this by going into my profile as follows:

C:\Documents and Settings\MYUSERNAME\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\ProjectAssemblies

There are four HIDDEN files in there that make up what is apparently the toolbox cache.  If you erase them, they will be re-generated and #13119 will go back to General.  As I said, these files appear to be hidden so configure the file explorer accordingly.

Second problem: my User controls disappeared from the toolbox.
I was able to fix it by going into the VS menus:

Visual Studio "Tools" menu

"Options" submenu

"Windows Form Designer" tab 
"General" tab 
Set "AutoToolboxPopulate" to "True"

Comment: Thanks, Vanof. this worked for me. I did find my toolbox files were not in projectassemblies subfolder. I deleted those 4 toolbox files and all the projectassemblies subfolders and all worked again.